# How to tall gcc that I want no more than 50% occupation per core while compiling/linking?

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, linker

I wonder if it is possible having N cores on production server tall gcc that I want it to use  50% of each core while compiling/linking? Can we start gcc from some other application that would allow it to use only half of cpu?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to halve the number of parallel jobs `make` runs instead?

Comment: It would occupy $jobs ammount of cores... 100%... Having some other important processes already running in all cores we will put our server at risk

Comment: My suspicion is that there is very little measurable difference between a task running "50% of the time on each core" vs. "100% of the time on half the cores". Either way, half of the CPU resources are available to other tasks, and the other half will be preemptively shared between `gcc` and other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

gcc, like most programs, has no built-in way to slow itself down. You could write a wrapper program that spawns a subprocess, and then repeatedly uses the POSIX functions `usleep` and `kill` in a loop to stop and restart it until it finishes. However, I am wondering why you need to use each core 50% of the time, rather than using half of the cores 100% of the time -- which, as has already been pointed out, is far easier to accomplish by adjusting the number of parallel jobs `make` runs. For example, `make -j 2` will limit the number of `gcc` processes to 2.

Edit: You may also be able to achieve your goal by running `make` with a high niceness level.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you request is not possible.